# Styled component not showing ::after pseudo class if content is an empty string

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am having problems findign a solution to this. In styled components I am using the after pseudo element. It works as long as I have the **content** value set to something, otherwise it doesen't show up. I need it to be empty (just as in plain CSS). What is the way to do it?

```
 export default css`
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  &::after {
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 11px);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px 0px rgba(var(--rgb-black),0.16);
  }´
```

Comment: But what do you want to achieve? What is your parent element? Div ? You didn't specified it and you need to specify display also and check what is happening. Your parent should also have position relative

Comment: @Freestyle09 as I see he has issue to display pseudo element if content is an empty string, which in traditional css this is not a problem.

Comment: Try to reproduce this example on stackblitz etc.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set the height of ::after

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem also, I couldn't get styled-components to render a `:after` pseudo element without using a non-empty content string. But making the text invisible was an acceptable workaround for me:

```
&::after { 
  content: "a"; //use non-empty string
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0); //make it invisible
  display: inline-block; //so width & height can be set
}
```

Here is the complete example on CodePen: https://codepen.io/remyho427/pen/VwMNeaG